# Parsing a WAV/PCM audio

Tags: audio, wav, audio-recording, pcm

This might be a stupid question. But I'd like to know whether or not there's usable (as in not just background noise) data within a wav file. Shouldn't be a problem - well, that's what I thought. But look at the hex - this is a part of a 16bit stereo WAV PCM file containing audacity created silence.

```
00000000   52 49 46 46  54 13 08 00  57 41 56 45  RIFFT...WAVE
0000000C   66 6D 74 20  10 00 00 00  01 00 02 00  fmt ........
00000018   44 AC 00 00  10 B1 02 00  04 00 10 00  D...........
00000024   64 61 74 61  30 13 08 00  00 00 01 00  data0.......
00000030   FE FF 02 00  FE FF 02 00  FF FF FF FF  ............
0000003C   02 00 FE FF  02 00 FE FF  01 00 00 00  ............
00000048   00 00 FF FF  02 00 FD FF  04 00 FC FF  ............
00000054   03 00 FE FF  01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  ............
00000060   00 00 FF FF  02 00 FE FF  02 00 FF FF  ............
0000006C   FF FF 02 00  FE FF 02 00  FF FF 00 00  ............
00000078   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  01 00 FF FF  ............
00000084   00 00 00 00  00 00 01 00  00 00 FE FF  ............
00000090   02 00 FE FF  02 00 00 00  FE FF 03 00  ............
0000009C   FC FF 04 00  FC FF 04 00  FD FF 02 00  ............
000000A8   FF FF 00 00  00 00 FF FF  02 00 FF FF  ............
000000B4   00 00 01 00  FD FF 04 00  FD FF 02 00  ............
000000C0   FE FF 02 00  FF FF 01 00  FF FF 00 00  ............
000000CC   00 00 01 00  FF FF 02 00  FD FF 03 00  ............
000000D8   FD FF 03 00  FD FF 03 00  FD FF 03 00  ............
000000E4   FD FF 02 00  FF FF 00 00  02 00 FC FF  ............
```

Now - I would have expected a lot of zeros, but that's not what hexedit tells me. Would somebody please enlighten me?

Thank you.

Michaela